# Python: transform data set

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I have the following data set

```
            id  type  value
0             1   A    10
1             1   C   120
2             2   B    20
3             2   C    40
4             3   A    10
5             3   B    50
```

I want in python to transform it to be like `(1,A,10,C,120) (2,B,20,C,40) (3,A,10,B,50)`

Any suggestion would be much appreciated

Comment: Start from [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/), Read about [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html) and [this](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html). Finally use [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) and solve your problem. As for the question it is too broad for Stack Overflow. See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Also, watch [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/talks.html#pycon-us-2015) video and look at [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/api.html#id5) in the pandas docs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perform `groupby` w.r.t *id* column. Iterate over each group by converting the other two columns to a `list` and add the unique value corresponding to the *id* per group number alongside. Finally, convert them into a `tuple` and append these to a list.

```
grouped = df.groupby('id')
L = []
for _, grp in grouped:
    L.append(tuple(grouped.get_group(_)['id'].unique().tolist() + grp[['type','value']].values.ravel().tolist()))
print(L)
#[(1, 'A', 10, 'C', 120), (2, 'B', 20, 'C', 40), (3, 'A', 10, 'B', 50)]
```

Comment: thanks @Nickil Maveli, however after I run your implementation after the values another 'L' is being appended, is there anyway I can get rid of it?

Comment: You mean you do not want to keep them as a list? How do you want to store them? You could also try editing the question to show what is going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
L = df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: tuple([x['id'].iat[0]] + 
                                          x[['type','value']].values.flatten().tolist()))
                    .tolist()
print (L)
[(1, 'A', 10, 'C', 120), (2, 'B', 20, 'C', 40), (3, 'A', 10, 'B', 50)]
```